# Get real time number of twitter followers from several accounts

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, twitter

I would like to create a social media ranking with live numbers of facebook fans and twitter followers. Numbers would be directly updated in the table.

Any idea how to get these numbers?

Answer (score 0):

you can get facebook fans or like count from facebook graph api.

you can get twitter followers count from http://dev.twitter.com/doc/get/users/show.

Eg: http://api.twitter.com/1/users/show.json?screen_name=twitter to get details about 'twitter' in json format. replace json in link with xml to get output in xml format